# How to parse HTML "BLOCKS" to a table layout for every not empty tag?

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, dom

**Updated:** (things are more complicated including **blocks**, which I didn't explain from the start, but I understand that this should work with regex or something)

How to parse HTML blocks to a table layout for every not empty tag?
As an example, this HTML:

```
<p class="block1">
    <span class="styleclass2">
        <span class="styleclass25">
            <strong>
                <u></u>Some Text Here
            </strong>
            <br>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="styleclass5">
        <u>
            <a href="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a>
        </u>
    </span>
    <br>
    <span class="styleclass24">Some Text Here</span>
</p>
<p class="block2">
    <span class="styleclass2">
        <span class="styleclass25">
            <strong>
                <u></u>Some Text Here2
            </strong>
            <br>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="styleclass5">
        <u>
            <a href="http://www.example2.com">www.example2.com</a>
        </u>
    </span>
    <br>
    <span class="styleclass24">Some Text Here2</span>
</p>
```

and make these:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some Text Here</td>
        <td>www.example.com</td>
        <td>Some Text Here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some Text Here2</td>
        <td>www.example2.com</td>
        <td>Some Text Here2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The main idea is how to group this blocks to make a row for every block found...

Comment: Please post the PHP code that you are having trouble with. We aren't going to write it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions are magic, try this:

```
<?php
$string = '<p class="styleclass1">
    <span class="styleclass2">
        <span class="styleclass25">
            <strong>
                <u>Some Text Here</u>
            </strong>
            <br>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="styleclass5">
        <u>
            <a href="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a>
        </u>
    </span>
    <br>
    <span class="styleclass24">Some Text Here</span>
</p>';

$result = preg_match_all("/<\w+.*?>(.*?)<\/\w+>/", $string, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';

$output = '<table style="border: 1px solid #000;">';

foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
    $output .= '<tr>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    $output .= '</tr>';
}

$output .= '</table>';

echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: It works well, but have an issue when the text is out from the tag and stands in outer tag, like this: "<strong><u></u>Some Text Here</strong>"
instead of: "<strong><u>Some Text Here</u></strong>"

Answer (score 0):

hodgie code  :)

```
$html = <<<HERE
<p class="styleclass1">
    <span class="styleclass2">
        <span class="styleclass25">
            <strong>
                <u>Some Text Here</u>
            </strong>
            <br>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="styleclass5">
        <u>
            <a href="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a>
        </u>
    </span>
    <br>
    <span class="styleclass24">Some Text Here</span>
</p>
HERE;
preg_match_all('#>(.+)<#sU', $html, $matches);
if(isset($matches[1]))
{
    echo '<table border="1">';
    foreach($matches[1] as $val)
    {
        $val = trim($val);
        if(!empty($val))
            echo '<tr><td>' . $val . '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```